# Can I make Soap V1 Api Calls from a magento 2. version?

Tags: magento2, php, api, soap-api-v1

Was wondering if I could use the magento SOAP v1 API to consume data from a magento 2 version store.

Comment: I can say yes: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

Answer (score 1):

That's the whole point of an API.
You should be able to call it from anywhere else *
Since you can use the M1 API from any other platform / software / kitchen sink you should be able to make those calls from a magento 2 platform.

* some restrictions may apply